# Connection between subnet and superfilter

Tags: gn.general-topology, filters, nets

Let's define a net and subnet in this way:

- A net is any function of the form $n:(P,\le)\to X$ where $(P,\le)$ is a (preordered) directed set.
- A net $m:(P',\le)\to X$ is a subnet of the net $n:(P,\le)\to X$ iff there is a function:
  $$\theta:(P',\le)\to (P,\le)$$
  which is increasing:
  $$x'\le y' \to \theta(x')\le\theta (y')$$
  and cofinal:
  $$(\forall p\in P)(\exists p'\in P')(p\le\theta(p'))$$
  and $m=n\circ\theta$.
- The filter assigned to a net $n:(P\le)\to X$ is the filter generated by
  $$\lbrace \lbrace n(x)\mid x\ge p  \rbrace \mid p\in P\rbrace$$
  on X. We denote this filter by $\mathcal F_n$,

My question is:

Are there nets $m:(P',\le)\to X$ and $n:(P,\le)\to X$ with
$$\mathcal F_n\subseteq \mathcal F_m$$
such that $m$ is not a subnet of $n$?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there are other possibilities to assign a net to a filter. It is possible to do it in a such way that finer filter gives a subnet. This is discussed in [Pete L. Clarks' notes on general topology](http://www.math.uga.edu/~pete/expositions.html). I will also mention that there exist [several definitions of subnet](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/topo/subnets2.pdf). The AA-subnet is defined in such a way, that finer filter corresponds to a subnet; but for this definition of subnet this fact is rather trivial.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for the references (+1). Your first link seems defunct.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. It seems that Pete L. Clark moved the site here: http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/expositions2012.html ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190220075803/http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/expositions2012.html)). The current link to the notes on general topology is http://math.uga.edu/~pete/pointset2018.pdf ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20190220075822/http://math.uga.edu/~pete/pointset2018.pdf)).

Comment: I'll include also [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20190220075944/http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/topo/subnets2.pdf) for the second link. (I should have done this when I first posted this, I do apologize.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks (+1+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Let Z be the integers, let X consist of a single point and let m : {0} -> X and n : Z -> X be constant functions. Then n and m give the same filter but m cannot be
a subnet of n since no single integer in Z is cofinal.